# I cannot load some pages after configuring CiviCRM Webform

Tags: webforms, installation, civicrm

I installed Drupal 9.3.5 and configured Webform 6.2. When I try to load the setting and other pages, I get this error.

> Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: Route "webform.config.libraries" does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteProvider->getRouteByName() (line 206 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/RouteProvider.php).
> Drupal\Core\Routing\UrlGenerator->getRoute() (Line: 270)
> Drupal\Core\Routing\UrlGenerator->generateFromRoute() (Line: 105)
> Drupal\Core\Render\MetadataBubblingUrlGenerator->generateFromRoute() (Line: 763)
> Drupal\Core\Url->toString() (Line: 132)
> Drupal\webform\WebformLibrariesManager->requirements() (Line: 108)
> webform_requirements()
> call_user_func_array() (Line: 403)
> Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandler->invokeAll() (Line: 109)
> Drupal\system\SystemManager->listRequirements() (Line: 93)
> Drupal\system\SystemManager->checkRequirements() (Line: 122)
> Drupal\system\Controller\SystemController->overview()
> call_user_func_array() (Line: 123)
> Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber{closure}() (Line: 564)
> Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext() (Line: 124)
> Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext() (Line: 97)
> Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber{closure}() (Line: 158)
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw() (Line: 80)
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle() (Line: 58)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle() (Line: 48)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle() (Line: 106)
> Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass() (Line: 85)
> Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle() (Line: 48)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle() (Line: 51)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle() (Line: 23)
> Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle() (Line: 708)
> Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle() (Line: 19)

I don't know how to fix this. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers. Can you tell us how you installed the Webform CiviCRM module (using Composer? Manually?)? Was the Webform module working fine before you added the CiviCRM module? Did you try to rebuild the cache afterwards?

Comment: I installed the webform civicrm integration using composer and then added the webform plugin from drupal UI. This is fresh installation I didn't add before.